# verilog bit shift with 1

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I'm trying to bit shift a value in verilog such that the replaced bits are 1's instead of 0's. i.e. I want to do `0001 << 1` such that it gives `0011` instead of `0010`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the command '<<' you use, puts zeros for remaining bits.
you can do like the following code:

imagine you have 4 bit variable (like your example) called A.

```
A = 4'b0000; 
A = {A[2:0], 1'b1};
```

with concatenation you can put one's instead of zeros.

or you can use 'or' function for this issue:

```
A = (A << 1) | 4'b0001;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
module ones_shift #(log2_width=2) (input [(2**log2_width)-1:0] A,  input [log2_width:0] SHIFT, output [(2**log2_width)-1:0] As);

  wire [(2**log2_width)-1:0] Ai, Ais;

  assign Ai = ~A;
  assign Ais = Ai << SHIFT;
  assign As = ~Ais;

endmodule
```

ie BITWISE INVERT -> LOGICAL SHIFT LEFT -> BITWISE INVERT

This will work for any valid shift value.

http://www.edaplayground.com/x/YWK

Answer (score 0):

Would you be able to do something like:

`(x << 1) + 1`

or

`(x << 1) | 1`

Answer (score 0):

To have the shift work with up to the number of bits the following example pre pads the input with 1's shifts then selects the MSBs:

```
localparam WIDTH = 4;
// Create temp with 1's as padding
wire [WIDTH*2 -1 :0] pad   = {A, {4{1'b1}}};
wire [WIDTH*2 -1 :0] shift = pad << 1;

// Select MSB with 1's shifted in
wire [WIDTH-1 : 0] result = shift[WIDTH*2 -1 : WIDTH];
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use this,

a = (1'b1 << count) - 1;

Assign count to a value equal to the no.of 1's to be filled from LSB.

Answer (score 0):

```
function bit[31:0] cal_mask_value (int size);
    bit [31:0] mask_value;

    mask_value = 32'hFFFFFFFF << size;
    mask_value = ~mask_value;
    return mask_value;
endfunction
```

Comment: Although this code might solve the problem, a good answer should also explain **what** the code does and **how** it helps.

Comment: Eg : Lets take the size = 2. Then the first line causes mask_value = 32'hFFFFFFFC. The Second line then inverts this value so you get 32'h00000003 essentially shifting 1s into the mask rather than 0s

Answer (score 0):

x |= x<<1; // assumes x starts as 1